# Batch file. If statements in if statements

Tags: batch, batch-file

I am trying to write this code:

```
If %dropmode%==on (
If %drop% LEQ %potiondrop% (
set /a potion=%potion%+1
)
If %drop2% LEQ %potiondrop% (
set /a potion=%potion%+1
)
)
```

So, condition "if %drop2% LEQ %potiondrop%" doesn't work, but "if %drop% LEQ %potiondrop%" is working. What to do?

Comment: What output do you get on the screen (when you delete or comment out your `ECHO OFF` statement)?

Comment: If ... (
    potion=0+1
    )
    If ... (
    potion=0+1
    )
    echo 1

Comment: It occurs to me that I should have asked the question, “What makes you believe that the first `SET` statement is working and the second one isn’t?” I guess your answer to that would be, “Both `IF` conditions are true, but `potion` comes out only one higher than its value at the beginning of the `IF`.” You might be surprised by what happens if you change the second `SET` statement to say `set /a potion=%potion%+2` or `set /a potion=%potion%+10`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the Windows Command Prompt / Command-Line Interpreter (CLI),
known as CMD.EXE, has a bug (well, I’m sure Microsoft thinks that it’s a feature) wherein,
when it reads a block construct like `IF … ( … )` or a `FOR` loop,
it interprets all `%variable_name%` variables *immediately*,
before the loop or block is executed. 
In your example, if `potion` is 0 when you enter the `If %dropmode%==on ( … )` block,
then all occurrences of `%potion%` inside that block evaluate to 0,
and so both of your `set` statements are processed as `set /a potion=0+1`,
even if you change `potion` inside the block. 
This is apparent from the screen output your reported.

The fix is to tell CMD to allow variables to be expanded at the right time,
when the statements referring to them are executed.  You do this by adding

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
```

somewhere near the beginning of your batch file, and changing your counting code to look like

```
    set /a potion=!potion!+1
```

using the `!variable_name!` form to activate the delayed expansion. 
See `SET /?` and `SETLOCAL /?` for more information.

---

P.S. Another solution is simply to remove the `%` characters from the `set` statements
and say

```
set /a potion=potion+1
```